# Random Walk in Java

Tags: java

A random walk is a stochastic process in which a particle moves one step at a time from state to state in a structured space. For us, the state space will be Z, the set of integers. The particle starts in an initial state S[0] ∈ Z. If, after i ≥ 0 steps, the particle is in state S[i], then in step i + 1, it moves to state S[i] + 1 with probability p and to state S[i] − 1 with probability q; it cannot stand still. Of course, p + q = 1. If S[0] = 5 and 0 < p < 1, then the sequence 5,4,3,4,3,2,3,2,3,4 is a possible sequence of states for the particle if it moves 9 times.

Write a program that will simulate a random walk for a given number of steps and that will compute certain statistics for the random walk. The parameters for a simulation come from standard input as a single line of parameters, consisting of (1) the initial state S[0]; (2) the value of p; and (3) the number of steps to simulate.

Note: I'm writing this in Java. 
So far I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int iState = rand.nextInt();
    int particle = iState;
    double pValue = 0.60;
    int numSteps = rand.nextInt() + 1;
    int nSteps = 0;

    if (numSteps>=0) {
        System.out.println(particle);
        while (nSteps<numSteps); {

            if (rand.nextDouble() < pValue)
                particle++;

            else
                particle--;

            System.out.println(particle);
            nSteps++;

        }

    }
```

Something seems to be going wrong though, so I'm stuck.

*EDIT: Thanks guys, somehow I didn't catch that semicolon.*

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

*EDIT 2:* Okay, so I have the code working correctly; however, in the end I am supposed to listed the maximum, minimum, and average values. Is this possible to do without creating a new variable for each iState value? My new code is

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int iState = rand.nextInt();
    double pValue = 0.60;
    int numSteps = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    int nSteps = 0;

    if (numSteps>=0) {
        System.out.println(iState);
        while (nSteps<numSteps) {

            if (rand.nextDouble() < pValue)
                iState++;

            else
                iState--;

            System.out.println(iState);
            nSteps++;
```

Comment: What, exactly, is going wrong?

Comment: It's only printing out one value. I need it to print out all the values of particle until nSteps is equal to numSteps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* your problem is that you need to delete the semicolon in the line

```
while (nSteps<numSteps); {
```

Also, you *almost certainly* don't want to iterate for `rand.nextInt() + 1` steps, since `rand.nextInt()` could be negative.  You might mean `rand.nextInt(n)` where `n` is some upper bound, though, or you might just set it to `n`.

UPDATE: If you need to track the minimum, maximum, and average values, you might do something like

```
 int min = iState; // initial value
 int max = iState; // initial value
 long total = iState; // initial value
```

Then, after each iteration, you say

```
 min = Math.min(min, iState);
 max = Math.max(max, iState);
 total += iState;
```

and then at the end of the iteration, your minimum is in `min`, your maximum is in `max`, and your average is `(double) total / numSteps`.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you mean by this. The program only runs if the (numSteps>=0)?

Comment: Correct...because otherwise you would be trying to run your program for less than zero steps, which ends up being "not running at all."

Comment: Done, sorry it took me so long. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon after you declare the condition for your while loop. Simply remove it and it should work.

```
    while (nSteps<numSteps);
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch your semicolons!

`while (nSteps<numSteps); {` should be `while (nSteps<numSteps) {`.

Answer (score 0):

Implement bernoulli function for determining which state to move for given p and q. For eg) since p=0.6 =. q=0.4.  Use 10 balls, 6 red, 4 blue and pick a ball and see what color it is. If its red, go to state+1 and if its blue, go state-1.

So you can have a random number generation of 1-10 with 1-6 representing red and 7-10 representing blue. Use rand.nextInt(10)+1 for 1 to 10.

Also, you don't have to use 2 variables for representing same thing if you are not going to use it elsewhere (istate and particle).